# Create Universal Automator Action

Tags: objective-c, universal, automator

I'm trying to create a universal Automator action for Mac OS X 10.5 & above. Under `architectures` I have set `"i386 ppc"` and when compiled, Finder sees the binary as `"Universal"`. Automator however says that the action is not universal and won't run it. (when hitting `"Build & Go"` in Xcode it works)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Mac is an Intel Mac, check if Automator is running as 64 bit process (Activity Monitor can tell you that). If it is, it may not be able to load a binary that contains 32 bit only. In that case your binary must have been compiled for three architectures, i386, ppc and x86_64. Note, however, that in SDK 10.5, Cocoa was not available for x86_64, so you will have to use SDK 10.6 for the x86_64 variant, while keeping SDK 10.5 for the i386 and ppc variants. That is easily possible, though, you can create a custom build setting, named SDKROOT_x86_64, which will override the default SDK setting (named SDKROOT), but only when building for the architecture x86_64. The value should be the absolute path to the SDK (I'm not sure if the shortcuts Apple usually uses for this setting will also work for a custom override).